# Does the op-amp output depend on the difference in input?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If there's two different input voltages, does the op-amp amplify the difference between them. Or is it only the differential op-amp that does this ? 
I'm confused!! .. I remember a question where the output voltage was 0 because the two input voltages were the same, but is that always true ?! But isn't the voltages of the two inputs the same anyway in the ideal op-amp ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there's two different input voltages, does the op-amp amplify the
>   difference between them ?

Yes. Because op-amp is a differential amplifier.
The output voltage for an ideal op-amp is 0 if the input voltages are equal.

> But isn't the voltages of the two inputs the same anyway in the ideal
>   op-amp ?!

Not always. The voltages at the input terminals becomes equal (virtual short) only when a negative feedback is provided to the op-amp. It does not apply to op-amp circuits with out negative feedback (*eg.,* comparator, schmitt trigger, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

An op-amp does amplify the difference between the two inputs, but the gain of an op amp is generally very, very high (>10,000) so the input difference required to drive the op amp output from one end of the range to the other is very small.  For an op amp with a gain of 10,000 on +/- 15 volt rails, the output swing is 30 volts while the input difference to drive that output swing is 3 mV.  In other words, the difference between the + and - inputs of this op amp should not exceed 3 mV so long as the output is not being driven into the rail.  An ideal op amp simply takes the limit as the gain goes to infinity, driving the input voltage difference to zero.

This is done because the gain of the op amp is not necessarily linear - it can vary depending on the input and output voltages.  Generally the gain will decrease as the output voltage nears the rails.  The gain can also depend on the common-mode input voltage as well.  The high gain means that when you add a feedback loop, the closed-loop gain will be much more linear than the open-loop gain, even though the op amp open-loop gain is not so nice.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mustafa as per my knowledge

op-amp can Amplify the difference of different input voltage.This job done by all different op-amp configuration not only differential op-amp.Most other configuration of op-amp (Differentiators,Integrators,etc) you may saw non inverting terminal connected to ground and the differential input equal to Input voltage at inverting terminal.So,It look like the output is depend upon amplification of only inverting input.If we connected some other voltage to non inverting terminal also then the output vary depend upon differential input.

In ideal case if same voltage applied to two differential terminal of op-amp then the output will be zero.But practically it won't happen due to output offset voltage.

If any wrong in m statement then sorry for that & please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

An op-amp does not obligatory have a differential input but as the differential input is more universal and versatile, nowadays almost all the op-amps are equipped with it (maybe current-feedback amplifiers are an exception). In some cases (e.g., in inverting configurations) the non-inverting input is unused and it is simply grounded.